# YA book - boy meditates for strength and intelligence

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

Looking for a book I read as a child in the 80s. Either 1 book with 2 plots or 2 books.
Hero was a young boy, a more evolved human, who could meditate and use that to gain enhancements. The common enhancement was great strength, I think another was faster thinking.
One plot line was about the boy being caught on a hijacked plane.
The second plot line had a giant laser in the side of a mountain.
Not much to go on, but it was a long time ago!